# Dapr Exponential backoff for RETRY (AzureServiceBus)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-bicep, dapr, azure-container-apps

Currently deployed services to the Azure container apps and they communicate through the azure service bus

During communication, a service will send 4000 messages some messages will throw errors because of the database max connections (200) to the database, therefore the messages have to be retried, But the problem is that the is no backoff time before a message is retried therefore most of those messages end up in the Dead letter queue after reaching the `maxDeliveryCount`.

Is there a metadata field on the Dapr component spec like `backOffInitialInterval` to set the time to wait before resending the message?

below is my bicep file

```
resource daprComponent 'daprComponents@2022-03-01' = {
    name: 'ifms-dapr-pubsub'
    properties: {
      componentType: 'pubsub.azure.servicebus'
      version: 'v1'
      secrets: [
        {
          name: 'service-bus-connection-string'
          value: 'Endpoint=sb://${serviceBusName}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=${listKeys('${serviceBusId}/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey', serviceBusApiVersion).primaryKey}'
        }
      ]
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'connectionString'
          secretRef: 'service-bus-connection-string'
        }
        {
          name: 'maxDeliveryCount'
          value: '1000'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus) there is a `Mode` and `Delay` in the `ServiceBusRetryOptions` for the client library

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial backoff interval for the retry policy, you can add a `metadata` field to your `daprComponent` resource with the name **`retryOptions`** and a value that includes a mode and delay property.

For example, you can set the back off retry policy to exponentially expand the delay starting with a value of `5` seconds as follows:

```
metadata: [
    {
        name: 'connectionString',
        secretRef: 'service-bus-connection-string',
    },
    {
        name: 'maxDeliveryCount',
        value: '1000',
    },
    {
        name: 'retryOptions',
        value: json({
            mode: 'exponential',
            delay: '00:00:05',
        }),
    },
],
```